# NameError: name 'xxxx' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get this error **"NameError: name 'destinataires' is not defined"** when I call a function inside 2 level functions:

I get an error even if I declare it as a global variable in the function:

```
def PostToFaceBookWall(msg):
    global destinataires
    try:
    ....
    except Exception as e:
        subject = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
        error  = str(e)
        SendMail(destinataires,subject,error)

def get_prices_for_next_days():
    ....
    subject = "xxxxx")
    html = "xxxxxx"
    SendMail(destinataires,subject,html) # NO PROBLEM WITH THIS INSTRUCTION : I GET MAIL
    PostToFaceBookWall(Msg2FB) # PROBLEM WITH THIS INSTRUCTION : I GET ERROR 
         
    
def SendMail(dest,sujet, msg):
    """Send a mail"""
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    destinataires = ['xxxxx@xxxx.xxx'] #a global variable
    get_prices_for_next_days()
```

Is level inclusion function limited?
A global variable defined in a function is not known inside sub function called?

Comment: What have you done to correct it tho?

Comment: I always get an error message, i did not fix it.

Comment: This should be fairly easy to distill into a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Please do that; it will make it easier for us to see what goes wrong, and you may find the problem yourself in the process!

Comment: There is something else that you did not include here.  You can call any function inside a function. There should not be a problem.

Comment: How many files do you have? Do you have only one file or multiple files?

Comment: In fact 2 files : 1 main and 1 with functions

Comment: Can't reproduce your error, see [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/PunctualAdorableMapping#main.py)

Comment: I don't understand  i can't reproduce my error (because cache on Python server perhaps????

Answer (score -1):

**I think you have to pass destinataires to get_prices_for_next_days() function**

*You cant accesses the destinataires in get_price_for_next_day() function with out passing*

Comment: The variable is global. You can access it.

Comment: I believe this answer is incorrect. `destinataires` is defined within the global scope, and is thus accessible within called functions (as long as it is not redefined in function scope).